# CreateTrackbar() is awkward with OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: opencv

I want to create a track bar in OpenCV 2.4.3. I write a sample code for that as regular, but the output is not like before.

[image]

This is my sample code and I'm using QT creator 5 on windows platform.

```
 int aa=5;
 cv::namedWindow("Cut histogram edges input image",1);
 cv::createTrackbar("histogram edges clipping limit", "Cut histogram edges input image",&aa,50);
 cv::namedWindow("Retina Parvo", 1);
```

Does anybody know why my output window is like the image above?
Thanks

Edited:

The following is what I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Maybeyou can ad a "before" picture too?

Comment: The output image is Ok. My problem is about trackbar in the above which is not like nice smooth track bar as before.

Comment: I think the trackbar you are looking for is not from OpenCV. It is probably a QT or other graphic library trackbar. OpenCV's trackbar always looks as yours

Comment: @AnderBiguri Oh. I didn't noticed that.So Thank you